# ASP.NET Core Razor pages routing results in http 404 error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am using ASP.NET Core Razor pages and have this directive at the top of my Blog.cshtml

```
@page "/blog/{category?}/page/{pageNo?}"
```

Now I want these routes all to match to the above:

```
/blog
```

-> It is similar like saying category is null add page by default and pageNo is null

```
/blog/aspnet
```

-> It is like saying category is `aspnet` add page by default and pageNo is null

```
/blog/page/1
```

-> It is like saying category is null page is there and pageNo is 1

```
/blog/aspnet/page/1
```

-> It is like saying category is aspnet page is there and pageNo is 1

What changes do I have to make?

I tried to make use of `AddPageRoute` but the below is not working:

```
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorPagesOptions(options => {

    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/blog", "blog/{category?}/page/{pageNo?}");    
});
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: HI @K V Sharma, any update here?

Comment: @Rena sorry. Accepted the answer. Yes it worked fine!! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure your Blog page locates in `Pages` folder(`/Pages/Blog.cshtml`).

If you have this directive at the top of `Blog.cshtml`:

```
@page "/blog/{category?}/page/{pageNo?}"
```

Be sure also make use of `AddPageRoute` like below:

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorPagesOptions(options => {
    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/blog", "blog/{category?}");
    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/blog", "blog/{category?}/page");
    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/blog", "blog/page/{pageNo?}");  
});
```